# How to save csv file in mongodb using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I found an example, how to save a csv file, but I got an error, do you know how to fix it? Also, please let me know if it is possible to save it in another way.

csv-save.js

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const csvtojson = require("csvtojson");

// let url = "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/";
let url = "mongodb://test1:1234@localhost:27017/";

csvtojson()
  .fromFile("bezkoder.csv")
  .then(csvData => {
    console.log(csvData);

    mongodb.connect(
      url,
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
      (err, client) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        client
          .db("cro")
          .collection("cro1")
          .insertMany(csvData, (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log(`Inserted: ${res.insertedCount} rows`);
            client.close();
          });
      }
    );
  });
```

bezkoder.csv

```
id,name,description,createdAt
1,Node.js,JavaScript runtime environment,2019-09-03
2,Vue.js,JavaScript Framework for building UI,2019-09-06
3,Angular.js,Platform for building mobile & desktop web app,2019-09-09
```

Error content
(MongoError: Authentication failed.)

Comment: if you just want to upload a csv to a collection, use `mongoimport` from cli

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "Error content (MongoError: Authentication failed.)" then you have an authentication error that you need to resolve before you can connect to your database.